# Using inline function kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inline

I know there was documented in main kotlin page, but there is no clear explanation about when to use it, why this function need a receiver as a function. What would be the correct way to create a correct definition of inline function.

1. This is inline function

```kotlin
inline fun String?.toDateString(rawDateFormat: String = MMMM_DD_YYYY, outputDate: String = MM_DD_YYYY, block: (date: String) -> String): String {
    return try {
        var sdf = SimpleDateFormat(rawDateFormat, Locale.US)
        val date = sdf.parse(this.orEmpty())
        sdf = SimpleDateFormat(outputDate, Locale.US)
        block(sdf.format(date ?: Date()).orEmpty())
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        block("")
    }
}
```

2. The same way we also can do

```kotlin
inline fun String?.toDateString(rawDateFormat: String = MMMM_DD_YYYY, outputDate: String = MM_DD_YYYY): String {
    return try {
        var sdf = SimpleDateFormat(rawDateFormat, Locale.US)
        val date = sdf.parse(this.orEmpty())
        sdf = SimpleDateFormat(outputDate, Locale.US)
        sdf.format(date ?: Date()).orEmpty()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

If anyone could have a detail explanation about this?

Edit:

I understand that the inline function will insert the code whenever it called by the compiler. But this come to my attention, when I want to use inline function without functional parameter receiver type the warning show as this in which should have a better explain. I also want to understand why this is such recommendation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things here.

First, you ask about using a function with a receiver.  In both cases here, the receiver is the `String?` part of `String?.toDateString()`.  It means that you can call the function *as if* it were a method of String, e.g. `"2021-01-15 12:00:00".toDateString(…)`.

The original `String?` is accessible as `this` within the function; you can see it in the `sdf.parse(this.orEmpty())` call.  (It's not always as obvious as this; you could simply call `sdf.parse(orEmpty())`, where the `this.` is implied.)

Then you ask about [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions).  All you have to do is to mark the function as `inline`, and the compiler will automatically insert its code wherever it's called, instead of defining a function in the usual way.  But you don't need to worry about how it's implemented; there are just a few visible effects in the code.  In particular, if a function is inline and accepts a function parameter, then its lambda can do a few things (such as calling `return`) that it couldn't otherwise do.

Which leads us to what I think is your real question: about the `block` function parameter.  Your first example has this parameter, with the type `(date: String) -> String` — i.e. a function taking a single `String` parameter and returning another `String`.  (The technical term for this is that `toDateString()` is a [higher-order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions).)

The `toDateString()` function calls this `block` function before returning, applying it to the date string it has formatted before returning it to the caller.

As to why it does this, it's hard to tell.  That's why we put documentation comments before functions: to explain anything that's not obvious from the code!  Ideally, there would be a comment explaining why you're required to supply a `block` lamdba (or function reference), when it's not vital to what the function does.

There are times when blocks passed this way are very useful.  For example, the [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) function accepts an optional `transform` parameter, which it applies to each item before joining it to the list.  If it didn't, the effect would be a lot more awkward to obtain.  (You'd probably have to apply a `map()` to the collection before calling `joinToString()`, which would be less efficient.)

But this isn't one of those times.  As your second example shows, `toDateString()` would work perfectly well without the `block` parameter — and then if you needed to pass the result through another function, you could just call it on `toDateString()`'s result.

Perhaps if you included a link to the ‘main kotlin page’ where you saw this, it might give some more context?

---

The edited question also asks about the IDE warning.  This is shown when it thinks inlining a function won't give a significant improvement.

When no lambdas are involved, the only potential benefit from inlining a function is performance, and that's a trade-off.  It *might* avoid the overhead of a function call wherever it's called — but the Java runtime will often inline small functions anyway, all on its own.  And having the compiler do the inlining comes at the cost of duplicating the function's code everywhere it's called; the increased code size is less likely to fit into memory caches, and less likely to be optimised by the Java runtime — so that can end up reducing the performance overall.  Because this isn't always obvious, the IDE gives a warning.

It's different when lambdas are involved, though.  In that case, inlining affects functionality: for example, it allows [non-local returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) and [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).  So in that case there are good reasons for using `inline` regardless of any performance implications, and the IDE doesn't give the warning.

(In fact, if a function calls a lambda it's passed, inlining can have a more significant performance benefit: not only does the function itself get inlined, but the lambda itself usually does as well, removing two levels of function call — and the lambda is often called repeatedly, so there can be a real saving.)

Comment: Thank for the great explanation, I have add more details about the questions that put on the attention.